# I function and menu_link

Tags: theming

I need to put an id in menu links  i have this code from here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

And have found the code i need but am struggling where to place it in the function. This code https://api.drupal.org/comment/45408#comment-45408:

```
l( t('Refresh Page'), $path . '/getdata', array(
              'attributes' => array(
                'id' => '', 
                'class' => 'btn-small btn-primary '
              ),'query' => drupal_get_destination() , 'html' => TRUE)),

    );
```

Where would it go, i know what i need, but i am having difficulty doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module to place different menu attributes to your menu links:

**[Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)**

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.
>
> You should use this module when
>
> - You want to "nofollow" certain menu items to sculpt the flow of PageRank through your site.
> - You want to give a menu item an ID so you can easily select it using jQuery.
> - You want to add additional classes or styles to a menu item.

You can also add the ID using theme_menu_link like you were using above, you would place that code in your template.php of your theme.

If you use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module you can print out the `$variables` array and see the different parts of the array there. You would basically want to use the mlid and the attributes part of the link to build out the ID (see code snippet below).

```
$element['#attributes']['id'] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];
```

If you need any other information just let me know, thanks!

Comment: thank this is a real help. But all the themes are already set up i just need to add that bit of code to menu_link. But don't know where, this is a help though.

Comment: The menu attribute is just a module, module readme would have instructions for that most of the time. The code part if you choose that path would go info your themes template.php (and replace theme_menu_link with YOURTHEMENAME_menu_link). Maybe that will help.

Comment: No that won't help me, but thanks

Comment: Are you meaning what line to put the code on?

Comment: Yep, i am to ad id's to the anchors. I found the code to indicate what to out but i don't know how to execute it.

Comment: Hey i got it to work, this code did it $element['#attributes']['id'] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid']; but how can i put a different id on the left hand navigation. Currently this id for all menu links. But i'm struggling to put a different id on the side navigation, if you see what i men.

Comment: So you have a different Id for every link but you want the side menu (probably secondary menu) to have an id of something like `secondary-menu-22` ?